# How can I trigger a build in Azure pipelines by pushing tags to github

Tags: git, github, azure-pipelines, git-tag

I am trying to trigger a build in Azure pipelines when a new tag is pushed to my github repository in the following way (dev being the name of the tag):

```
git tag dev
git push --tags
```

The build should not be triggered by any push of a specific commit to a repo, only when a tag is pushed.

I have tried various configurations of the trigger section of my azure-pipelines.yml file with no success:

```
trigger:
  - master
  - refs/tags/dev
```

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - refs/tags/dev
```

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  tags:
    include:
    - dev
```

I also tried by replacing 'dev' with wildcards but also nothing. This should be possible according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) but I cannot seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Here is my full azure-pipelines.yml just in case:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  tags:
    include:
    - dev
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: In `push` to master the pipeline triggered?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes the build is being triggered from the master branch properly

Comment: Try `dev*`, maybe it will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who's hitting this issue, there is a thread over on the VS developercommunity forum here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/656727/build-pipeline-trigger-from-git-tag-is-not-working.html?childToView=661889#comment-661889

The TLDR; is that MS is chasing it. Something appears to have broken some time after Friday, July 19th, 2019...  the approach was working up-to and including that Friday.

While I'm here, one gotcha that hit me while I had this working is that I needed to explicitly exclude `'*'` in the `pr:` section in addition to my trigger / tag config... otherwise PRs were also triggering my pipeline when I only wanted it triggered by tag pushes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, fingers crossed it's fixed soon.